# Manifest merger failed while creating Maps Activity

Tags: android-studio

I got stucked in this rude error, please suggest some solution to it.

When I creates new_project -> Map_Activity for the first time,
I got this error:

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>       is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:11:5-39:19 to override.

But when I pasted

> 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:11:5-39:19 to override

Then, I got new error:

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

I'd looked for some of solutions on stackoverflow and github, but my error is not resolving.

All files are default, I had'nt made any change even then the error is coming from default :(

Your solution would be a great help for me. Please give your ideas in order to resolve this issue with newProject with MapActivity. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
To solve it, just add the following line in your gradle.properties file:
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true


this should be in your build.gradle
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'

Hope this will help. I resolved the issue by doing this
```